# Home page changes

Tags: support, status-bydesign

Is it possible to change what appears on the home page?

Seems to me the very first thing we should see is a list of all questions with the newest ones at the top. Right now you have to go hunting for that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to change what appears on the home page. To get a list of the *newest* questions, you have to switch to the 'questions' page.

There's some work being done around the home-page experience and maybe it's time to bring this up again. I never particularly understood the design were we have a "home page" listing of questions…  and then a completely *separate* (and different) "questions page" listing of questions. But for now, to get to the newest questions, click on the 'questions' link at the top of the page.